# Is there any way to calculate 1 week forward returns FROM a long signal?

Tags: pine-script

I would like to calculate the one week forward returns of a long signal I have. I got all the dates stored in an array but I cannot figure out the % change calculation. How do I measure it starting when the long signal fires?

```
// Defining future return intervals
return1WeekFuture = close / close[7] - 1
return2WeeksFuture = close / close[14] - 1
return3WeeksFuture = close / close[21] - 1
return1MonthFuture = close / close[30] - 1
return2MonthsFuture = close / close[60] - 1
return3MonthsFuture = close / close[90] - 1

plotshape(long, style=shape.triangleup, size=size.small, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green)

// Use 'varip' for the array to persist its contents across bars
var counter = 0
varip dateArray = array.new_string(0)
varip owArray = array.new_string(0)

// Add the date to the array when 'long' condition is met
if (long)
    counter := counter + 1
    array.push(dateArray, str.tostring(year) + "-" + str.tostring(month) + "-" + str.tostring(dayofmonth))
    array.push(owArray, str.tostring(return1WeekFuture))
    

// Display the date from the array in a table
var table cond = table.new(position.bottom_right, 100, 100)
if (array.size(dateArray) > 0)
    table.cell(cond, 1, 1, text= "DATE", text_color=color.white, text_size=size.small, text_halign=text.align_center, bgcolor = color.blue)
    for i = 0 to counter - 1
        table.cell(cond, 1, i, text=array.get(dateArray, i), text_color=color.black, text_size=size.small, text_halign=text.align_center)
        table.cell(cond, 2, i, text=array.get(owArray, i), text_color=color.black, text_size=size.small, text_halign=text.align_center)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the modified code

```
// Defining future return intervals
return1WeekFuture = close / close[7] - 1
return2WeeksFuture = close / close[14] - 1
return3WeeksFuture = close / close[21] - 1
return1MonthFuture = close / close[30] - 1
return2MonthsFuture = close / close[60] - 1
return3MonthsFuture = close / close[90] - 1

// Use 'varip' for the array to persist its contents across bars
var counter = 0
varip dateArray = array.new_string(0)
var owArray = array.new_float(0)

// Add the date to the array when the 'long' condition is met
if (long)
    counter := counter + 1
    array.push(dateArray, str.tostring(year) + "-" + str.tostring(month) + "-" + str.tostring(dayofmonth))

// Calculate the one-week forward returns for all of the dates in the array
for i = 0 to array.size(dateArray) - 1
    owArray.push(close(dateArray[i]) / close(dateArray[i] + 7) - 1)

// Display the dates and one-week forward returns in a table
var table cond = table.new(position.bottom_right, 100, 100)
if (array.size(dateArray) > 0)
    table.cell(cond, 1, 1, text="DATE", text_color=color.white, text_size=size.small, text_halign=text.align_center, bgcolor=color.blue)
    table.cell(cond, 2, 1, text="RETURN", text_color=color.white, text_size=size.small, text_halign=text.align_center, bgcolor=color.blue)
    for i = 0 to array.size(dateArray) - 1
        table.cell(cond, 1, i + 2, text=array.get(dateArray, i), text_color=color.black, text_size=size.small, text_halign=text.align_center)
        table.cell(cond, 2, i + 2, text=str.tostring(array.get(owArray, i) * 100) + "%", text_color=color.black, text_size=size.small, text_halign=text.align_center)
```

The use the above code, use the following

```
//@version=4
study("One-Week Forward Returns", shorttitle="1W Returns", overlay=true)

// Enter a long position when the MACD crosses above its signal line
longCondition = (macd > macdsignal) and (macd[1] <= macdsignal[1])

// Initialize arrays to store the date and one-week forward returns
var dateArray = array.new_datetime(na)
var returnsArray = array.new_float(na)

// Calculate and store the date when the long signal occurs
if longCondition
    array.push(dateArray, time)

// Calculate one-week forward returns for all of the dates in the array
for i = 0 to array.size(dateArray) - 1
    longBarIndex = array.get(dateArray, i)
    // Calculate the bar index for one week later
    oneWeekLaterBarIndex = longBarIndex + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60) // 7 days in seconds
    // Store the date when the long signal occurred
    array.push(dateArray, time[oneWeekLaterBarIndex])
    // Calculate and store the one-week forward return
    oneWeekReturn = (close[oneWeekLaterBarIndex] / close[longBarIndex]) - 1
    array.push(returnsArray, oneWeekReturn)

// Display the date and one-week forward returns in a table
if array.size(dateArray) > 0
    table = table.new(position.bottom_right, 2, ["Date", "1-Week Return"])
    for i = 0 to array.size(dateArray) - 1
        table.cell(table, 0, i, tostring(array.get(dateArray, i, na))
        table.cell(table, 1, i, tostring(array.get(returnsArray, i, na), "0.00%"))

plotshape(series=longCondition, style=shape.triangleup, size=size.small, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green)
```

Hope this solves the bug.
Lemme tell you, your approach was nearly there. Good show

Comment: hello my friend, i apologize for the late rely. I did figure out a different way to achieve the goal. But, i will be testing your method today/tomorrow. If it works properly, i will share the entire script with you (buy signal included).